# transition from one css to other

Tags: javascript

i want to develop a webpage in which i need to change css after every 60 sec and images after every 30sec.

But during the transition from one css to other it takes so much time to download the css and images,also transition is not very smooth.

So, is there any way by which i could download all the css and images, that i need for the transition, when the page loads first time??

I am using following code to change css:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var interval

            $(document).ready(function() {
            interval = setInterval("tog()", 60000);
            });
</script>

function tog()


{

if (currentStyle == "css/style_purple.css") 
  {

         $("#stylesheet").attr({href : "css/style_green.css"});

        currentStyle = "css/style_green.css";

   } 

else 

if (currentStyle == "css/style_green.css") 
 {

    currentStyle = $("#stylesheet").attr({href : "css/style_orange.css"});

     currentStyle = "css/style_orange.css";

   } 

else if (currentStyle == "css/style_orange.css") 
{

    currentStyle = $("#stylesheet").attr({href : "css/style_red.css"});

    currentStyle = "css/style_red.css";

}
else if (currentStyle == "css/style_purple.css") 
{  

   currentStyle = $("#stylesheet").attr({href : "css/style_red.css"});

   currentStyle = "css/style_red.css";

} 

else

{

   currentStyle =  $("#stylesheet").attr({href : "css/style_purple.css"});

    currentStyle = "css/style_purple.css";

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the attribute of object (i.e. `class` ) and apply style to class.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var flag = 1;

$(function (){
  setInterval('change()', 2000);
})

function change(){  
    if(flag%2 == 1)
    {       
        $('.one').attr('class', 'two');
        $('.1').attr('class', '2');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.two').attr('class', 'one');
        $('.2').attr('class', '1');        
    }
    flag++;
}
</script>
<html>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="1"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: @experimentX,can u give me any example or some code? m not getting exactly how to implement

Comment: @Ketaki this is just a simple one, you can create multiple classes and do it, but it's kinda tedious job

Comment: @experimentX..yeah...do u knw any other way to do dis caz the site has been already delivered so i think it will take time to club all the properties for 4 style sheets in to a single one.

Comment: @Ketaki well, i guess in don't know the other way, ... for images as you said. Probably the answer might be `caching` and I don't know much on this topic.

Comment: @experimentX...hey i got da solution...i simply attached all css file using <link href="cssfile.css"> and
attached images to image tag nd just added style=display:none